# Date type: string literal and date literal - different formatting of date

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
 Me.Load
         Dim str As String = "1-2-2014"
         Dim dte As Date = CDate(str)
         MsgBox(dte.Month)
     End Sub
```

The date literal is: #1/2/2014#.  This is always interpreted as 2nd January 2014 as discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx.  However, in the code fragment above the date is interpreted as 1st February 2014.  Is the local regional settings used when you pass a string?

Comment: you arent passing a string, you are converting one.  NET assumes that "1-2-2014" is the valid date time for your region/culture and makes a date based on that.  Use `convert.ToDateTime` or `DateTime.ParseExact` if you want/need to specify a format or culture for the string version. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24175610/1070452

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the `Date` **Type** MSDN docs, but creating a string `"1-2-2014"` which is not a `Date` type and wont act like one.  The note about the order and using `#` applies only to a `DateTime` variable:

```
Dim myDt As Date =  #1/2/2014#
```

Also look at what [MSDN says about CDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx):

> In general, hard-coding dates and times as strings (as shown in this example) is not recommended. Use date literals and time literals, such as #Feb 12, 1969# and #4:45:23 PM#, instead.

As a string, it is difficult to know what format/culture it follows to know how to convert it back.  Instead, keep Date-based data items as Date type variables and simple format them for the user, reports, MsgBox etc:

```
' DISPLAY a date anyway we want, without changing the value:
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("hh:mm M/d/yyyy"))    ' => 05:55 2/11/2010
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("HH.mm M/d/yyyy"))    ' => 17.55 2/11/2010
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))  ' => 02/11/2010 17:55
```

NET and VB are always going to assume a string is in the current culture format, unless told otherwise.  `CDate` is simplified so you cant pass a format, but other convert functions allow you to specify the culture or format:

```
Dim myStr As String = "17:55 2/11/2010"    ' ad odd date/time format
Dim dtVar As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, 
                           "HH:mm M/dd/yyyy", 
                           Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```